# Flask-WTFforms TypeError: __init__() takes 2 arguments 3 are given

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Ive been trying to build this flask login system, but keep getting this error. Ive looked up with particular error and the suggestions don't seem to fit the problem in this instance.

I took out two(email and name) of the fields in the template and it worked, but I am not sure why as I imagine you should be able to have as many fields as you want. Also, it will not commit the user data to the database.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, Email
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sosecretbro'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:////Users/myname/Desktop/officeplace/database.db'
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(50))
    username = db.Column('username', db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column('email', db.String(50))


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=3, max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=15)])
    password = StringField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired, Email(message=None)])

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=15)])
    password = StringField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'We here now'


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return '<h1>' 'New user created' '<h1>'
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)


if (__name__) == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Templates -

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Register Here
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='register.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-register" method="POST" action="/register">
        <h2 class="form-register-heading">Register, Fool.</h2>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.name) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

Traceback -

```
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/officeplace.py", line 43, in register
if form.validate_on_submit():
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
if not field.validate(self, extra):
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 204, in validate
stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/officeplace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 224, in _run_validation_chain
validator(form, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: parantheses missing in `InputRequired` in `email` field in `RegisterForm` class

Comment: Wow. Can't thank you enough man.